# Save form data to localstorage, display it in innerHTML and delete it with delete data button

Tags: html, local-storage, angular2-localstorage, localstack

I've got this code for saving form data into localstorage,then displaying it by replacing `<span id="recalledtext" >Dear Visitors</span>` with . innerHTML.

```
   <HTML>
    <head>
    <script>
    function myfunction1(){texttosave = document.getElementById('textline').value ; localStorage.setItem('mynumber', texttosave); } function myfunction2(){document.getElementById('recalledtext').innerHTML = localStorage.getItem('mynumber'); }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body onload='myfunction2()'>
    <input type="text" id="textline" placeholder="Enter Your Name"/> <button id="rememberer" onclick='myfunction1()'>Save</button>
    <br>
     Welcome<span id="recalledtext" >Dear Visitors</span> Refresh the page to see changes
    </body>
    </HTML>
```

It was working perfectly, but I also wanted a delete data button. So I've changed the code into this:

```
<HTML>
<head>
<script>
function myfunction1(){texttosave = document.getElementById('textline').value ; localStorage.setItem('mynumber', texttosave); } function myfunction2(){document.getElementById('recalledtext').innerHTML = localStorage.getItem('mynumber'); } function myfunction3() localStorage.removeItem('mynumber'); return '';}
</script>
</head>
<body onload='myfunction2()'>
<input type="text" id="textline" placeholder="Enter Your Name"/> <button id="rememberer" onclick='myfunction1()'>Save</button> <button id="recaller" onclick='myfunction3()'>Delete Your Name</button>
<br>
 Welcome<span id="recalledtext" >Dear Visitors</span> Refresh the page to see changes
</body>
</HTML>.
```

But after adding function myfunction3() , the code was completely stopped working.

Answer (score 1):

I've found the answer myself. I was for you a long time then I've started checking the JavaScript code. There was a missing character "{" 
Here is the right code

```
    <HTML><head>
<script>
function myfunction1(){texttosave = document.getElementById('textline').value ; localStorage.setItem('mynumber', texttosave); } function myfunction2(){document.getElementById('recalledtext').innerHTML = localStorage.getItem('mynumber'); } function myfunction3() localStorage.removeItem('mynumber'); return '';}
</script>
</head>
<body onload='myfunction2()'>
<input type="text" id="textline" placeholder="Enter Your Name"/> <button id="rememberer" onclick='myfunction1()'>remember text</button> <button id="recaller" onclick='myfunction3()'>Delete Your Name</button>
<br>
 Welcome<span id="recalledtext" >Dear Visitors</span> Refresh the page to see changes
</body>
</HTML>
```